# How use a js text injected into console of Firefox to change Background Image of Site - Sample Provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I only have this example, but it does exactly what I want to do; but it also does a bunch of other stuff- and for the wrong site. (This js provided is just the example that I know it's possible I just don't know how to get "only that" piece and ONLY that).

I want a small js text that I can inject into the console pop up CTRL-SHIFT-K of Firefox, that will change the background image of the website (same site used in this script).

But that's all I want. I just want to make my own background when on the site.

The script here does change the background (its a command in the begining (background image JPG).

How would I isolate that into a short snip of js... that I could use as a standalone to only do just that and nothing more?

I tried to modify this, and did reading up on scripting JS, but I dont code, so I only have gotten errors.

Any help would be so much appreciated! :)

**The Background lines of code begin at LINE 45-46. - THIS IS ALL I WANT - ONLY A SMALL SCRIPT TO DO JUST THE BACKGROUND, EVERYTHING ELSE GONE**

THANK YOU!

```js
 var flameBot, betspeed, aftermanualtrigger, swaplosscount, swapcount, loop, loopenabled, betData, condition, profit, target, losscount, totalloss, totalwin, currentbet, basebet, mainmult, initmult, result, afterwin, UI = '',
     UI2 = '';
 profit = 0;
 var streakcounter = [];
var balance;
 var winstreak = 0;
 betspeed = 613;
 loopcount = 0;
 betstarted = false;
 loopenabled = false;
 aftermanualtrigger = false;
 afterwin = false;
 var consecutive = 0,
     singlewin = 0;
 swaplosscount = 0;
 var conseclossenabled = false;
 var swapnextwin = false;
 swapcount = 0;
 var firstInit = true;
 if (firstInit == true) {
  balance = Math.floor($('div.hero span.btn__text.select div').text()*1e8);
 }
 flameBot = {
     initialize: {
         init1: function () {
             var lib = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" /><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>';
             $(lib).appendTo('head');
             setTimeout(function () {
                 flameBot.initialize.init2();
             }, 1000);
         },
         init2: function () {
             losscount = 0;
             totalloss = 0;
             totalwin = 0;
             $('.hero__main').empty().css('width', '550px') & $('.hero__main').css("padding", "0") & $(UI).appendTo('.hero__main') &
                 $('#flameBot').tabs() & $('button').button().css('font-size', '13px').css('padding', '5px');
             $('#stats th').css("width", "20%").css("font-size", "14px");
             $('#hilo, #resetorzero').buttonset();
             $('#flameBot li').css('font-size', '15px');
             $('#flameBot #resetorzero').css('font-size', '13px');
             $('#flameBot div[role=tabpanel] td').css('padding', 1);
             $('.hero__main').css('margin-top', '-75px');
             $('#stats2 th').css('width', '6.25%');
             var css = '',
                 backgroundurl = 'http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/HD-backgrounds-3.jpg';
             css += '<style id="paraDark">';
             css += 'header, .tabs, .slideout__content__inside, .chat__you *, .btn, .hero__main, .rollrow-dark, .rollbox--prominent, .chat__input-holder{background-color:#121212 !important;color:#ccc !important;}';
             css += 'time{color:#ccc !important;}';
             css += 'div.tabs > div > div.live-data-header > div{background-color:#111111;border-top:1px solid #777; border-bottom:1px solid #777;}';
             css += '.btn,.btn--secondary.btn--active,.btn--secondary.btn--selector, .btn--submit:last-child{border:1px solid #777 !important;background-color:#242130 !important;color:#ccc!important;}';
             css += '.btn:hover,.btn--secondary.btn--active:hover,.btn--secondary.btn--selector:hover{border:1px solid #777 !important;background-color:#322E47 !important;color:#ccc!important;}';
             css += '.hero{margin-bottom:0px;background:url("' + backgroundurl + '") no-repeat 50% 50%;}';
             css += '.slideout *{color:#ccc;}';
             css += '.tabs{padding-top:20px;border-top:1px solid #777 !important;}';
             css += 'header{border: 1px solid #777 !important;border-left:none !important;border-right:none !important;}';
             css += '.rollrow-thin, .rollrow-dark .chat__input-holder {background-color:#212121;}';
             css += '.input{background-color:#323232 !important;color:#ccc;}';
             css += '.action-open-slideout{background-color:#121212 !important;}';
             css += 'span.admin{color:white !important}';

             css += '</style>';
             $(css).appendTo('head');
             $('#stats2, #stats3').css('margin-left', '10px');
             $('#stats3 th').css('width', '25%').css('text-align', 'center');
             $('#stats3').css('width', '50%').css('text-align', 'center');
             $('<center><button onclick="flameBot.API.bet();" class="btn btn--primary btn--huge btn--limited btn--block text--center" id="spinner2">Roll</button></center>').appendTo('.hero__main');
             $('#resetorzero').css('font-size', '11px');
             $('#lastbet th').css('text-align', 'center');
             $('#lastbet th').css('padding', '3px');
             $('#lastbet tr').css('border-top', '1px solid #fff');
             $('#lastbet3 > tbody > tr').css('background', '#181818', 'important');
             $('#lastbet2 > tbody').css('background', '#181818');
             $('.hero__main').css('border', '1px solid #777');


             for (i = 0; i < $('#stats2 th').length; i++) {
                 streakcounter.push(0);
             }
             for (i = 0; i < $('#stats2 th').length; i++) {
                 var lol = $('#stats2 th')[i];
                 lol.textContent = (i + 1).toString() + "(" + streakcounter[i] + ")";
             }
             $('#resetstats').click(function () {
                 streakcounter = [];
                 for (i = 0; i < $('#stats2 th').length; i++) {
                     streakcounter.push(0);
                 }
                 for (i = 0; i < $('#stats2 th').length; i++) {
                     var lol = $('#stats2 th')[i];
                     lol.textContent = (i + 1).toString() + "(" + streakcounter[i] + ")";
                 }
                 totalwin = 0;
                 totalloss = 0;
                 profit = 0;
                 consecutive = 0,
                     singlewin = 0;
                 winstreak = 0;
                 losscount = 0;
                 flameBot.API.addRow();

             });
             $('#start').click(function () {

                 looptimes = 999999999;
                 if (loopenabled === false) {
                     loopenabled = true;

                     loop = setInterval(function () {

                         if (loopcount >= looptimes) {
                             clearInterval(loop);
                             loopcount = 0;
                             loopenabled = false;
                         } else {
                             if (betstarted === true) {} else {
                                 flameBot.API.bet();
                             }
                         }
                     }, betspeed);

                 }

             });
             $('#stop').click(function () {
                 clearInterval(loop);
                 loopenabled = false;
                 loopcount = 0;
             });
             $('#setparams').click(function () {
                 flameBot.API.setParams();
             })
         }
     },
     tools: {
         dec2Sat: function (decimal) {
             return (Math.floor(decimal * 1e8));
         },
         token: function () {
             return localStorage.token;
         },
         satToDec: function (satoshi) {
             return ((satoshi / 1e8).toFixed(8));
         },

     },
     API: {
         onLoss: function () {
             totalloss++;
             losscount++;
             if (afterwin === true) {
                 afterwin = false;
                 flameBot.API.setParams();
             }
             if (winstreak >= 2) {
                 consecutive++;
                 $('#consecutive').text(consecutive);
                 winstreak = 0;

             }
             if (winstreak == 1) {
                 singlewin++;
                 $('#single').text(singlewin);
                 winstreak = 0;
             }
             if ($('#swaplossesenabled').is(':checked') === true) {
                 swaplosscount++;
                 if (swaplosscount >= $('#swaplosses').val()) {
                     swapnextwin = true;
                     swaplosscount = 0;
                 }
             }
             if ($('#afterlossesenabled').is(':checked') === true) {
                 if (losscount >= $('#afterlosses').val()) {
                     if ($('#aftermanualenabled').is(':checked') === true) {

                         if (aftermanualtrigger === true) {} else {
                             var r = prompt("Enter '1' to reset to base. Enter '2' to bet 0 until win. Enter '3' to stop.");
                             if (r == 1) {
                                 aftermanualtrigger = false;
                                 currentbet = basebet;
                                 losscount = 0;
                             } else if (r == 2) {
                                 aftermanualtrigger = true;
                                 currentbet = 0;
                             } else {
                                 clearInterval(loop);
                                 aftermanualtrigger = false;
                                 loopenabled = false;
                             }
                         }

                     } else {
                         if ($('input:radio[name=resetorzero]:checked').val() == 'orzero') {
                             currentbet = 0;
                         } else if ($('input:radio[name=resetorzero]:checked').val() == 'orstop') {
                             clearInterval(loop);
                             loopenabled = false;
                         } else if ($('input:radio[name=resetorzero]:checked').val() == 'resetor') {
                             losscount = 0;
                             currentbet = basebet;
                         }
                     }

                 } else {
                     if (losscount == $('#startlosses').val()) {
                         currentbet = currentbet * $('#initialmultiplier').val();
                     } else if (losscount > $('#startlosses').val()) {
                         currentbet = currentbet * $('#mainmultiplier').val();
                     }
                 }
             } else {
                 if (losscount == $('#startlosses').val()) {
                     currentbet = currentbet * $('#initialmultiplier').val();
                 } else if (losscount > $('#startlosses').val()) {
                     currentbet = currentbet * $('#mainmultiplier').val();
                 }
             }
             flameBot.API.addRow();
         },
         onWin: function () {
          if ($('#betdivisorenabled').is(':checked') === true) {
               basebet = Math.floor(balance/$('#betdivisor').val());
             }
             winstreak++;
             conseclossenabled = false;
             if (swapnextwin === true) {
                 flameBot.API.swap();
                 swapnextwin = false;
             }
             if ($('#afterwinenabled').is(':checked') == true) {
                 if (afterwin === false) {
                     afterwin = true;
                 }
             }
             if (aftermanualtrigger === true) {
                 aftermanualtrigger = false
             }
             totalwin++;
             swaplosscount = 0;
             var streak = losscount;
             if (losscount >= 250) {
                 losscount = 250;
             }
             streakcounter[losscount - 1] ++;
             losscount = 0;
             currentbet = basebet;
             flameBot.API.addRow();
         },
         setParams: function () {
             losscount = 0;
             aftermanualtrigger = false;
             swaplosscount = 0;
             swapcount = 0;
             initmult = $('#initialmultiplier').val();
             mainmult = $('#mainmultiplier').val();
             if ($('#betdivisorenabled').is(':checked') === true) {
                basebet = Math.floor(balance/$('#betdivisor').val());
                currentbet = basebet;
             } else {
             basebet = flameBot.tools.dec2Sat($('#basebet').val());
             currentbet = basebet;
           }
             if ($('input:radio[name=hilo]:checked').val() == 'hi') {
                 condition = '>';
                 target = (99.99 - (99 / $('#chance').val())).toFixed(2);
             } else if ($('input:radio[name=hilo]:checked').val() == 'lo') {
                 condition = '<';
                 target = (99 / $('#chance').val()).toFixed(2);
             } else if ($('input:radio[name=hilo]:checked').val() == 'swap') {
                 condition = '<';
                 target = 0 + (99 / $('#chance').val()).toFixed(2);
             }
         },
         addRow: function () {

             var bettable = '',
                 bettab = '#lastbet2';
             bettable += '<tr><td>' + flameBot.tools.satToDec(result.bet.amount) + '</td>';
             bettable += '<td>' + result.bet.multiplier + 'x' + '</td>'; /* return bet payout */
             bettable += '<td>' + (result.bet.target).toFixed(2) + '</td>'; /* return target*/
             bettable += '<td>' + result.bet.roll + '</td>'; /* return roll */
             bettable += '<td id="proff">' + flameBot.tools.satToDec(result.bet.profit) + '</td></tr>';

             var stattable = '',
                 stattab = '#lastbet3';
             stattable += '<tr><td style="color:blue;">' + flameBot.tools.satToDec(result.user.balance) + '</td><td style="color:white;">' + losscount + '</td><td style="color:blue;">' + totalwin + '</td><td style="color:white;">' + totalloss + '</td><td id="profit">' + (profit).toFixed(8) + '</td></tr>';
             $(stattab).empty();
             $(stattab).prepend(stattable);
             stattable = '';
             if ($(bettab + ' tbody tr').length >= 30) {
                 $(bettab + ' tr').last().remove();
                 $(bettab).prepend(bettable);
                 bettable = '';
             } else if ($(bettab).length < 30) {
                 $(bettab).prepend(bettable);
                 bettable = '';
             }
             for (i = 0; i < $('#stats2 th').length; i++) {
                 var lol = $('#stats2 th')[i];
                 lol.textContent = (i + 1).toString() + "(" + streakcounter[i] + ")";
             }
             $('#stats2 th:nth-child(19)').text('>' + $('#stats2 th:nth-child(19)').text());
             $('#lastbet2 *, #lastbet3 *, #lastbet *, #proff').css('text-align', 'center');
             $('#lastbet2 *, #lastbet3 *, #lastbet *').css('width', '20%');
             $('#lastbet *').css('padding', '5px');
             $('#lastbet *').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #ccc');
             $('#result-1').css('padding', '5px');
             $('#lastbet2 *, #lastbet3 *, #proff').css('padding', '5px');
             $('#lastbet > tbody > tr > th:nth-child(2)').css('border-top', '1px solid #ddd');
             if (profit >= 0) {
                 $('#profit').css('color', 'blue');
             } else {
                 $('#profit').css('color', 'white');
             }
             if (result.bet.win === true) {
                 $('#proff:first').css('color', 'blue');
             } else {
                 $('#proff:first').css('color', 'white');
             }
             betstarted = false;
         },

         bet: function () {
             betstarted = true;
             if ($('#maxbetenabled').is(':checked') === true) {
                 if ((currentbet / 1e8) >= $('#maxbet').val()) {
                     $('#setparams').click();
                 }
             }
             if ($('#afterwinenabled').is(':checked') === true) {
                 if (afterwin === true) {
                     currentbet = ($('#afterwinamount').val() * 1e8).toFixed(8);
                 }
             }
             if ($('#clossenabled').is(':checked') === true) {
                 if (losscount >= $('#clossafter').val()) {
                     if (conseclossenabled === false) {
                         conseclossenabled = true;
                         currentbet = Math.floor($('#clossbet').val() * 1e8);
                     }
                 }
             }
             var betData = {
                 amount: currentbet,
                 condition: condition,
                 target: target,
             };
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'https://api.primedice.com/api/bet?access_token=' + flameBot.tools.token(),
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: betData,
                 datatype: 'jsonp',
                 success: function (data) {
                     result = data;
                     balance = result.user.balance;
                     profit = parseFloat(profit) + parseFloat(flameBot.tools.satToDec(data.bet.profit));
                     if ($('input:radio[name=hilo]:checked').val() == 'swap') {
                         swapcount++;
                         if (swapcount >= $('#swapevery').val()) {
                             flameBot.API.swap();
                             swapcount = 0;
                         }
                     }
                     if (data.bet.win === true) {
                         $('span.btn__text.select div').text(flameBot.tools.satToDec(result.user.balance)).css('color', 'blue');
                         flameBot.API.onWin();
                     } else {
                         $('span.btn__text.select div').text(flameBot.tools.satToDec(result.user.balance)).css('color', 'white');
                         flameBot.API.onLoss();
                     }
                 },
                 error: function (errorThrown) {
                     betstarted = false;
                 }
             });
         },
         seedChange: function () {
             function seedgen() {
                 var seed = '';
                 var seedlength = 10;
                 var charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()';
                 for (var i = 0; i <= seedlength; i++)

                     seed += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

                 return seed;
             }
             var s = seedgen(),
                 url = 'https://api.primedice.com/api/seed?access_token=' + localStorage.token,
                 sData = {
                     seed: s
                 };

             $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: sData,
                 datatype: 'json',
                 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                     data2 = data;
                     $('#currentseed').val(data2.seeds.client);


                 },
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     return false;
                 }
             });
         },
         swap: function () {
             if (condition == '<') {
                 condition = '>';
                 target = (99.99 - (99 / $('#chance').val())).toFixed(2);
             } else if (condition == '>') {
                 condition = '<';
                 target = (99 / $('#chance').val()).toFixed(2);
             }
         },
     }
 }

 var UI = '';
 UI += '<table style="margin:0; text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;border-top: 1px solid #fff;"id="stats">';
 UI += '<thead><tr><th style="text-align:center;padding:3px;">Balance</th><th style="text-align:center;padding:3px;">Loss Streak</th><th style="text-align:center;padding:3px;">Total Wins</th><th style="text-align:center;padding:3px;">Total Losses</th><th style="text-align:center;">Total Profit</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody><table id="lastbet3"></table></table>';

 UI += '<table id="lastbet">';
 UI += '<tr><th>Bet</th><th>Payout</th><th>Game</th><th>Roll</th><th>Profit</th></tr></table>';
 UI += '<div style="max-height:150px !important;font-size:12px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;"><table id="lastbet2"></table></div>';
 UI += '<div id="flameBot" style="width:550px"><ul><li>';
 UI += '<a href="/play#basic">Basic Settings</a></li>';
 UI += '<li><a href="/play#onloss">On Loss</a></li>';
 UI += '<li><a href="/play#onlosstreak">Loss - Adv.</a></li>';
 UI += '<li><a href="/play#onwin">On Win</a></li>';
 //UI += '<li style="margin:8px;font-size:9px;margin-left:15px;text-align:center;"><span>FlameBot - v1.0</span></li>';
 UI += '</ul>';
 UI += '<div id="basic" style="font-size:17.5px;">';
 UI += '<table style="display:table;"><thead><tr><th>Basebet: </th><th>Chance:</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input id="basebet" placeholder="ex. 0.00001000" type="text"></td><td><input id="chance" placeholder="ex. 10 for 10x, 2 for 2x, etc." type="text"></td></tr></tbody><thead><tr><th>High/Low/Swap:</th><th>Swap Every:</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><div id="hilo"><input type="radio" id="hi" value="hi" name="hilo"><label for="hi">High</label> <input type="radio" id="lo" value="lo" name="hilo" checked="checked"><label for="lo">Low</label> <input type="radio" id="swap" value="swap" name="hilo"><label for="swap">Swap</label> </div></td><td><input id="swapevery" placeholder="# of rolls" type="text"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>';
 UI += '<div id="onloss" style="font-size:17.5px;">';
 UI += '<table style="display:table;"><thead><tr><th>Start Multipling: </th><th>Main Multiplier:</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input id="startlosses" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="after # of losses"type="text"></td><td><input id="mainmultiplier" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="2, 4, etc."type="text"></td></tr></tbody><thead><tr><th>Initial Multiplier</th><th>Max Bet: <input type="checkbox" id="maxbetenabled"></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input id="initialmultiplier" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="2, 4, etc."type="text"></td><td><input id="maxbet" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="ex. 0.001" type="text"></td></tr><tr><th>After: <input type="checkbox" id="clossenabled"></th><th>Change Bet To:</th></tr></thead></tr><tbody><tr><td><input id="clossafter" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="# of consecutive loss"type="text"></td><td><input id="clossbet" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="ex. 0.00100000"type="text"></td></tr></tbody></tbody><thead><tr><th>Divisible Basebet:</th><th>Basebet Divisor:</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input id="betdivisorenabled" style="text-align:center;" type="checkbox"></td><td><input id="betdivisor" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="ex. 0.00100000"type="text"></td></tr></tbody></tbody></table>';
 UI += '</div>';
 UI += '<div id="onlosstreak" style="font-size:17.5px;">';
 UI += '<table style="display:table;"><thead><tr><th>After: <input type="checkbox" id="afterlossesenabled"></th><th>Either: </th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input id="afterlosses" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="# of losses"type="text"></td><td><div id="resetorzero"><input type="radio" id="resetor" value="resetor" name="resetorzero"><label for="resetor">Reset to Base</label><input type="radio" id="orzero" value="orzero" name="resetorzero" checked="checked"><label for="orzero">Roll 0 to Win</label><input type="radio" id="orstop" value="orstop" name="resetorzero" checked="checked"><label for="orstop">Stop</label></div></td></tr></tbody><thead><tr><th>Manualy Choose?</th><th>Swap After: <input id="swaplossesenabled" type="checkbox"></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input id="aftermanualenabled" type="checkbox"></td><td><input id="swaplosses" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="# of losses" type="text"></td></tr></tbody></table>';
 UI += '</div>';
 UI += '<div style="font-size:17.5px;" id="onwin">';
 UI += '<table style="display:table;"><thead><tr><th>After Win:</th><th>Bet X Until Loss </th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="afterwinenabled"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="ex. 0.00002000" id="afterwinamount"></td></tr></tbody></table>';
 UI += '</div>';
 UI += '<div id="controlstat">';
 UI += '<center><div id="toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><div id="buttonz"><span id="startstop"><button id="start">Start</button><button id="stop">Stop</button></span><span id="set"><button id="setparams">Set Params</button><button id="resetstats">Reset Stats</button><br><button id="save">Save Settings</button><button id="load">Load Settings</button></div></center><br>';
 UI += '<table style="margin:3px;"id="stats2">';
 UI += '<span style="font-weight:bold;">Loss Streaks:</span>';
 UI += '<thead><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th><th>10</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>11</th><th>12</th><th>13</th><th>14</th><th>15</th><th>16</th><th>17</th><th>18</th><th>19</th><th>20</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>21</th><th>22</th><th>23</th><th>24</th><th>25</th><th>26</th><th>27</th><th>28</th><th>29</th><th>30</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>31</th><th>32</th><th>33</th><th>34</th><th>35</th><th>36</th><th>37</th><th>38</th><th>39</th><th>40</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>41</th><th>42</th><th>43</th><th>44</th><th>45</th><th>46</th><th>47</th><th>48</th><th>49</th><th>50</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>51</th><th>52</th><th>53</th><th>54</th><th>55</th><th>56</th><th>57</th><th>58</th><th>59</th><th>60</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>61</th><th>62</th><th>63</th><th>64</th><th>65</th><th>66</th><th>67</th><th>68</th><th>69</th><th>70</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>71</th><th>72</th><th>73</th><th>74</th><th>75</th><th>76</th><th>77</th><th>78</th><th>79</th><th>80</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>81</th><th>82</th><th>83</th><th>84</th><th>85</th><th>86</th><th>87</th><th>88</th><th>89</th><th>90</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th>91</th><th>92</th><th>93</th><th>94</th><th>95</th><th>96</th><th>97</th><th>98</th><th>99</th><th>100</th></tr></thead></table>';
 UI += '<table style="margin:3px;"id="stats3">';
 UI += '<span style="font-weight:bold;">Wins:</span>';
 UI += '<thead><tr><th>Single:</th><th>Consecutive:</th></tr>';
 UI += '<tr><th id="single">0</th><th id="consecutive">0</th></tr></thead></table>';
 UI += '</div>';
 UI += '</div>';
 flameBot.initialize.init1();
```

The Background lines of code begin at LINE 45-46.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Super helpful thank you. The code is already there. I have tried cutting and pasting and I keep getting errors. I read up on all the threads here, tried merging different js scripts I came across.   I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***small js text that I can inject into the console pop up CTRL-SHIFT-K of Firefox, that will change the background image of the website (same site used in this script)***

The code that you have posted (after view page source) is a static HTML page. You can change the background image of that html by adding following to line 36.

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(path/to/yourimage.png)');
```

Example :

```js
     flameBot = {
         initialize: {
             init1: function () {
                 var lib = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" /><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>';
$('body').css('background-image','url(path/to/yourimage.png)');                
 $(lib).appendTo('head');
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     flameBot.initialize.init2();
                 }, 1000);
             },
```

However , this will only work as a static HTML page ( Much like opening a text file on your browser , except you will be doing it with a new image).

Comment: Thank you this works!  I had tried something similar, but missed the body tag prior to .css. So it would inject but nothing would happen.  Thank you!

Comment: I will definitely upvote - as soon as I hit 15 reputation ;)  It wont let me yet. But I just started and have 8, so I'll come back in a week and upvote it. Thank you again for the help!!